# How to extends an abstract class with generics?

Tags: scala, generics, abstract

I am new to Scala. What I want to do is to create an abstract class named `EnhancedFirstOrderMinimizer` which extends another abstract class named `FirstOrderMinimizer`. However, the IDE tells me that "`Type mismatch, expected: nothing, actual: DF`".

Here is FirstOrderMinimizer:

```
abstract class FirstOrderMinimizer[T, DF <: StochasticDiffFunction[T]]
    (maxIter: Int = -1, tolerance: Double = 1E-6, improvementTol: Double = 1E-3,
     val minImprovementWindow: Int = 10,
     val numberOfImprovementFailures: Int = 1)
    (implicit space: NormedModule[T, Double])
    extends Minimizer[T, DF] with SerializableLogging {

protected def initialHistory(f: DF, init: T): History
  ...
  type History
  protected def initialHistory(f: DF, init: T): History
  protected def adjustFunction(f: DF): DF = f
  protected def adjust(newX: T, newGrad: T, newVal: Double): (Double, T) =
    (newVal, newGrad)
  protected def chooseDescentDirection(state: State, f: DF): T
  protected def determineStepSize(state: State, f: DF, direction: T): Double
  protected def takeStep(state: State, dir: T, stepSize:Double): T
  protected def updateHistory(newX: T, newGrad: T, newVal: Double,
                              f: DF, oldState: State): History

  def iterations(f: DF, init: T): Iterator[State] = {
    val adjustedFun = adjustFunction(f)
    infiniteIterations(f, initialState(adjustedFun, init))
      .takeUpToWhere(_.converged) 
  }
  ...
}
```

Here is `EnhancedFirstOrderMinimizer`:

```
EnhancedFirstOrderMinimizer[T, DF<:StochasticDiffFunction[T]]
    (maxIter: Int = -1, tolerance: Double=1E-6, improvementTol: Double=1E-3)
    extends FirstOrderMinimizer {

  override def iterations(f: DF, init: T): Iterator[State] = {
    val adjustedFun = adjustFunction(f)

    // f: Type mismatch, expected: nothing, actual: DF
    infiniteIterations(f, initialState(adjustedFun, init))
      .takeUpToWhere(_.converged)
  }
}
```

Could you please help me check it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that `f` is the wrong type for the first argument of `infiniteIterations`. We probably need to see where `infiniteIterations` is declared to know exactly what's going on.

But I think the quick answer to your extension problem is that `extends FirstOrderMinimizer` should be changed to `extends FirstOrderMinimizer[T, DF]`.